# plugin is not defined (cordova-plugin-googlemaps)

Tags: cordova, google-maps-api-3, cordova-plugins, html-framework-7

while trying to use cordova-plugin-googlemaps it displays plugin not defined.
I follow steps provided by https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-googlemaps. 
I get error in
$ var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap();
 produce "plugin is not defined" error.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was only working on android & ios device, you won't be able to open it from browser.

Comment: It does not, I am using Phonegap